# Vue3, VeeValidate4 - Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vee-validate

I can not figure it out, where is the problem. I am using VeeValidate (over CDN) to validate a simple form.
Form looks like this:

```
<form @submit="onSubmitClient" class="grid">
    <div class="col-5">
      <label for="firstName">Name </label>
      <input id="firstName" type="text" v-model="client.firstName"><br>
      <span class="field-error">{{ errors.firstName }}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-5">
      <label for="lastName">Last Name </label>
      <input id="lastName" type="text" v-model="client.lastName"><br>
      <span class="field-error">{{ errors.lastName }}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <label for="email">Email </label>
      <input id="email" type="email" v-model="client.email"><br>
      <span class="field-error">{{ errors.email }}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
      <button>Continue</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

And then i have this code for vaidation:

```
const schemaClient = {
      firstName: 'required|min:3',
      lastName: 'required|min:3',
      email: 'required|email'
    }

    const { handleSubmit } = VeeValidate.useForm({
      validationSchema: schemaClient
    })

    const onSubmitClient = handleSubmit(() => {
      emit('nextStep', data)
    })
    const { value: firstName, errorMessage: firstNameError } = VeeValidate.useField('firstName')
    const { value: lastName, errorMessage: lastNameError } = VeeValidate.useField('lastName')
    const { value: email, errorMessage: emailError } = VeeValidate.useField('email')
```

When I click on the button, to submit the form and if there are no validation errors, it emits an event to go to the next step via VueRouter. Everything works fine but in console i get the following errors:

```
vee-validate.min.js:6 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstName' of undefined
    at vee-validate.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ vee-validate.min.js:6
Promise.then (async)
Bt @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:776
unregister @ vee-validate.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ vee-validate.min.js:6
bt @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:720
_t @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:728
Zn.t.__weh.t.__weh @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:1564
J @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:159
Q @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:2868
G @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:2827
m @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:2236
(anonymous) @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:2565
n @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:192
I @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:2547
R @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:2385
m @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:2255
A @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:2357
O @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:2381
m @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:2252
(anonymous) @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:2565
n @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:192
bt @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:720
Ht @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:829
Promise.then (async)
It @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:784
Lt @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:788
(anonymous) @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:2970
Zo.h @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:2971
(anonymous) @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:283
de @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:282
scheduler @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:685
(anonymous) @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:283
de @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:282
set value @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:626
finalizeNavigation @ vue-router.global.js:3121
(anonymous) @ vue-router.global.js:2994
Promise.then (async)
pushWithRedirect @ vue-router.global.js:2966
push @ vue-router.global.js:2901
go2Step4 @ <stdin>:153
bt @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:720
_t @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:728
zt @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:853
(anonymous) @ Step3.js:115
(anonymous) @ vee-validate.min.js:6
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ vee-validate.min.js:6
bt @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:720
_t @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:728
n @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:3438
vee-validate.min.js:6 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'lastName' of undefined
    at vee-validate.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ vee-validate.min.js:6
Promise.then (async)
Bt @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:776
unregister @ vee-validate.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ vee-validate.min.js:6
bt @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:720
_t @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:728
Zn.t.__weh.t.__weh @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:1564
J @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:159
Q @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:2868
G @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:2827
m @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:2236
(anonymous) @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:2565
n @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:192
I @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:2547
R @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:2385
m @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:2255
A @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:2357
O @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:2381
m @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:2252
(anonymous) @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:2565
n @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:192
bt @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:720
Ht @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:829
Promise.then (async)
It @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:784
Lt @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:788
(anonymous) @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:2970
Zo.h @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:2971
(anonymous) @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:283
de @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:282
scheduler @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:685
(anonymous) @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:283
de @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:282
set value @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:626
finalizeNavigation @ vue-router.global.js:3121
(anonymous) @ vue-router.global.js:2994
Promise.then (async)
pushWithRedirect @ vue-router.global.js:2966
push @ vue-router.global.js:2901
go2Step4 @ <stdin>:153
bt @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:720
_t @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:728
zt @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:853
(anonymous) @ Step3.js:115
(anonymous) @ vee-validate.min.js:6
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ vee-validate.min.js:6
bt @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:720
_t @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:728
n @ vue.global.prod.js:formatted:3438
vee-validate.min.js:6 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined
    at vee-validate.min.js:6
```

I am looking at this for quite some time now but I just don't get it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the full source of your component, it is hard to tell the issue from the snippets you provided.

Answer (score 0):

I did not mention I was using these versions:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.0.0/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@4.0.5/dist/vue-router.global.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vee-validate@4.4.7/dist/vee-validate.min.js"></script>
```

after I changed this to:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router@4"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vee-validate@4.4.7/dist/vee-validate.min.js"></script>
```

..and now the error is gone.